# Cutting a layer out of a layer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cashapelayer

So I'm trying to cut a circle out of an existing layer; and here's my code:

```
    CGRect bounds = _containerLayer.bounds;
    CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    maskLayer.frame = bounds;
    maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    CGFloat smallCircleRadius = (frame.size.width - barWidth)/2;
    CGRect smallCircleRect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds) - smallCircleRadius, CGRectGetMidY(bounds) - smallCircleRadius, 2 * smallCircleRadius, 2 * smallCircleRadius);
    UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:smallCircleRect];
    [circlePath appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds]];
    maskLayer.path = circlePath.CGPath;
    maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;

    _containerLayer.mask = maskLayer;
```

This code does work, as I now see a black rectangle with a hollow circle in the middle. But the problem is that when I tried to set `maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;`, The whole thing including `_containerLayer` just disappears - I want to make the `fillColor` transparent so I can see what's originally in the `_containerLayer` (which wasn't cut out). What should I do to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: What if you add a UIView on top of the view, the use your code on the UIView, then you can see through?

Comment: @gabbler I can't because my `_containerLayer` is a `CALayer` so i can't add a subview to it.

Comment: Is `_containerLayer` a layer of a view?  do you want to be able to see the circle area of this view?

Comment: @gabbler yes it is a layer of the view (`[self addSubLayer: _containerLayer]`), and I want to be able to see what's displayed in the view through the cut-out circle, kinda like the scope on a sniper rifle.

Comment: So my suggestion is put another UIView on top of this view, they have the same frame. Make your _containerLayer as the top view's layer, then you will be able to see what underneath.